# Reloading Sinatra app on every request on Windows

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, reloading

I've set up `Rack::Reload` according to this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/sinatrarb/browse_thread/thread/a5cfc2b77a013a86)

```
# config.ru
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

set :environment, :development

require 'app'
run Sinatra::Application

# app.rb  
class Sinatra::Reloader < Rack::Reloader
  def safe_load(file, mtime, stderr = $stderr)
    if file == Sinatra::Application.app_file
      ::Sinatra::Application.reset!
      stderr.puts "#{self.class}: reseting routes"
    end
    super
  end
end

configure(:development) { use Sinatra::Reloader }

get '/' do
  'foo'
end
```

Running with thin via `thin start -R config.ru`, but it only reloads newly added routes. When I change already existing route, it still runs the old code.

When I add new route, it correctly reloads it, so it is accessible, but it doesn't reload anything else.

For example, if I changed routes to

```
get '/' do
  'bar'
end

get '/foo' do
  'baz'
end
```

Than `/` would still serve `foo`, even though it has changed, but `/foo` would correctly reload and serve `baz`.

**Is this normal behavior, or am I missing something?** I'd expect whole source file to be reloaded. The only way around I can think of right now is restarting whole webserver when filesystem changes.

I'm running on Windows Vista x64, so I can't use **shotgun** because of `fork()`.

Answer (score 21):

You could try [sinatra-reloader](http://github.com/rkh/sinatra-reloader), which is known to work well on Windows (also, it's faster than shotgun).

Comment: We had this problem ourselves, since two of my team use Windows, and two are on Macs. This is the solution we went with, seems to be working well so far.

Comment: not only faster but I find sinatra-reloader easier to use :-)

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
# config.ru
require 'rubygems'
require 'app'

set :environment, :development
run Sinatra::Application

# app.rb  
require 'sinatra'

class Sinatra::Reloader < Rack::Reloader
  def safe_load(file, mtime, stderr = $stderr)
    if file == File.expand_path(Sinatra::Application.app_file)
      ::Sinatra::Application.reset!
      stderr.puts "#{self.class}: reseting routes"
    end
    super
  end
end

configure(:development) { use Sinatra::Reloader }

get '/' do
  'foo'
end
```

It matters from where you have the require statement. But I find the following solution more  elegant and robust:

```
# config.ru
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'rack/reloader'
require 'app'

set :environment, :development

use Rack::Reloader, 0 if development?
run Sinatra::Application

# app.rb  
Sinatra::Application.reset! 
get '/' do
  'foo'
end
```

Comment: Perfect! For a modular app, run MyAppClassName (config.ru) and include the Sinatra::Application.reset! in the app class (app.rb).

Answer (score 0):

Does [Shotgun](http://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun) not work on Windows?

From the README:

```
                                Shotgun
```

This is an automatic reloading version of the rackup command that's shipped with
Rack. It can be used as an alternative to the complex reloading logic provided
by web frameworks or in environments that don't support application reloading.

The shotgun command starts one of Rack's supported servers (e.g., mongrel, thin,
webrick) and listens for requests but does not load any part of the actual
application. Each time a request is received, it forks, loads the application in
the child process, processes the request, and exits the child process. The
result is clean, application-wide reloading of all source files and templates on
each request.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your note about Shotgun

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using [Trinidad](http://github.com/calavera/trinidad) a JRuby Rack container based on Tomcat. In my experience it does change reloading by default without having to modify your source files. Bloody fast too. Obviously no good if you are using native libraries, but if you are deploying on Windows you are probably used to adopting a pure-ruby approach.

Its syntax is just as simple as the thin approach:

```
jruby -S trinidad -r config.ru
```

There is no Java specific yak shaving (i.e. creating web.xml or WARing up your Ruby app) and the gem is simple to install.